# integrate an angular 6 application into an existing HTML site as a simple JS file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can i add/integrate an Angular 6 application into an existing HTML site, can I include it as a single JS file ?

How can I bundle an Angular App into a single JS file ?

Thanks

Comment: Just go post code what you have done.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements). This will allow you to generate a custom web component which you can embed into a HTML page. [This tutorial](https://medium.com/@tomsu/building-web-components-with-angular-elements-746cd2a38d5b) has good information on how to end up with a single JS file that you can import in your HTML and then use as a custom element.

Comment: but how do you handle bootsrapping and routing of angular element app?

Comment: It seems to me that the tutorial explains how single components are made available to any HTML. But does this also work for a complete app consisting of many components?

Comment: Yes that can also be done although it can get a little complex. Manfred Steyer (https://github.com/manfredsteyer) has done a lot of work on this and has some great examples of dashboards loading components from different frameworks (which also have sub-components, etc).

Comment: @HumbleDolt The bootstrapping is part of how Angular Elements works. As for routing, I've seen if done by using hash based routing instead of history pushstate based routing. We had some success monkeypatching history.pushstate to provide a hook to handle the routing. Again, I think Manfred Steyer has the best examples of getting this stuff to work.

Comment: Also, full disclosure: we worked on this for a while but moved away from this solution because we couldn't solve problems with memory leaks (angular apps not being cleaned up properly) and the general complexity of the solution.